# What is MIME type for csv file of type BIN using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mime-types

I want to handle a csv file download using selenium.For this, I am setting the firefox profile.

I am able to download some of the csv file but I am unable to download a csv file which is of type BIN.

Can you please let me know what should be the MIME type for csv file of type BIN ?

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `applicaiton\csv` or `text\csv` mime types for setting your firefox profile, depending on the type of excel sheet you are trying to download.

Please refer other mime types for excel in this [link](http://mimeapplication.net/text-csv). If the above mimetypes didn't work try `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

Comment: How to apply mime type in selenium in chrome??

Answer (score 0):

As answer is already provided. Generally i used below add-on for firefox

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/
```

in Type column it display type which is required for us in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If above doesn't work, try this : **text/comma-separated-values**

For details you can visit this site - 
https://watirmelon.com/2011/09/07/determining-file-mime-types-to-autosave-using-firefox-watir-webd